# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask inspite of not doing anything on UI

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, populate, splash-screen

I have some data in a text file which I want to populate the database with while the splash screen is visible to the user. I tried it with AsyncTask but I get this error  **Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()** I understand that this error is thrown when we try to update UI in the AsyncTask thread. But I am not doing anything like that. Please help. I am new to android.
Here is my code:
AsyncTask:

```
       `public class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>'
```

doInBackground method

```
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    return 1234;
    }
```

From MainActivity constructor I call my DbHelper class which populates the database.

```
        `public  MainActivity(){
    Words word = new Words(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        word.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }`
```

My DbHelper onCreate does this.

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDatabase = db;
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_WORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_MEANING + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );
        try {
            loadWords();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the loadWords function is :

```
 private void loadWords() throws IOException {
          Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
           final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
           InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
         Words uff = new Words(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
         //  uff.close();
          // String line
               String line;
               try {
                    //if(!uff.ourDatabase.isOpen())
                        uff.open();

              // ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                   if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                   Log.d(TAG, "going to insert");
                   long id = createEntry(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                   Log.d(TAG, "After insert " + id);
                   if (id < 0) {
                       Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                   }
               }
               Log.d(TAG, "after whille loop");
               }

               catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                       Log.d(TAG, "open fail");

     } finally {
            uff.close();
               reader.close();
           }
           Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");

}
```

THis is what my logcat says:

```
    07-06 18:41:20.604: W/dalvikvm(2364): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception         (group=0x41fac2a0)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing  doInBackground()
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:772)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.sourabh.words.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:32)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.sourabh.words.LoadingTask.doInBackground(LoadingTask.java:69)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.sourabh.words.LoadingTask.doInBackground(LoadingTask.java:1)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    07-06 18:41:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2364):     ... 5 more
    07-06 18:41:21.009: D/libEGL(2364): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
```

Comment: You should read some basic android tutorials. Don't create instances of activities.

Comment: This question is very clear to anyone experienced with Android.  While it reveals a beginner-level conceptual mistake, there's nothing wrong with that - everyone makes mistakes, learning from them is important, and facilitating that is a key role of the site.  The poster is clearly aware of the usual cause of this exception and has attempted to investigate that, failing only due to the earlier conceptual mistake.  All the necessary information is presented in the question - it doesn't need down votes or close votes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. That support was much needed, down votes really do pull you down. I now understand my mistake and am working on it. Thanks for the quick response. Sorry I do not have the reputations to upvote your answer. I'll get that fixed too. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

As Luksprog says, you must not call the constructor of an Activity class - that is the job of the Android framework (and as an Activity is fundamentally a UI concept, it's not the least bit surprising that the superclass constructor involves UI operations)

If you need to reference something from your existing Activity instance, get/keep/pass a reference to the existing instance of the class - one that you created with `new` wouldn't be the same as the existing one anyway.

If you mean to create a new instance of an Activity, you use an Intent to ask Android to do that - you do not do it yourself.